# API内のループで、echoを使用して出力されたデータを、php内で受け取る方法

Tags: php, laravel

laravelで、検索結果をJSON出力するAPIを作成したのですが、出力するデータが多いため、分割でechoでデータを送信するよう作成しました。この場合、別の環境のphp内でそのAPIを実行し、データを全て受け取り、加工したいとき、どのように受け取ればいいでしょうか？
(ブラウザで実行すると正常に取得できます)

PHPで下記を実行するとNULLが返ってきます。

```
$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([~~]);
$response = $http->post('URL' ~~
var_dump(json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true));
exit;
```

[追記]
・APIからechoで送信されるデータ1回目

```
[
{data:[~~]},
```

・２回目

```
{data:[~~]},
```

・３回目

```
{code:200,message:~~}
]
```

・１回目から３回目を合わせるとjsonデータになります。

```
[
{data:[~~]},
{data:[~~]},
{code:200,message:~~}
]
```

Comment: 「データをすべて受け取り加工する」ってなんでしょうか？ てきとうにデータ量を減らすとかですか

Comment: laravelで作ったAPIに別のPHPから問い合わせるということなんでしょうか

Comment: 説明がわかりにくくすみません。laravelで作成したAPIを、別で作成したPHPで実行し、データを受け取りたいです。「データを全て受け取り加工する」の意味は、API側でechoで複数回データを送信しておりますので、そのデータを全て受け取るとjson形式のデータになります。そのjsonから配列に加工して使用したいという意味になります。

Comment: なるほどです、どんなJSONが得られて、どんな配列に加工したいんでしょうか

Comment: まずは、データの加工よりも、分割で送信されるデータを受け取りたいのですが、記載のコードでは受け取ることが出来ず、特殊な方法でしか受け取る事は出来ないのでしょうか？

Comment: 「受け取ることが出来ない」というのはどんな状態なんでしょうか？ API側でページングのような仕様を作ったなら呼び出し側でも複数回リクエストする必要がありますよね

Comment: 受け取るデータを追記してみました。APIの呼び出しは１回でループ内でecho送信しております。

Comment: そもそも論なんですがAPI側で分割しておいてから呼び出し側で結合する必要ってあるんでしょうか？ もしかして全く意味のないことをしてたりしませんか

Comment: 説明読めばわかると思いますが、API内で部分的にecho送信している意味は、送信するデータ量が多いため、一括で送信できないからです。ロジックは、一部のデータを作成し、echo送信、メモリクリア、echo送信、メモリクリア、などを行っております。これ以上説明する事がございませんので、わかる方のみご回答頂ければと思います。

Comment: 今まさに、巨大なデータを分割または、位置指定で取ろうしています。　番号を振って指定できる様にしています。例：
[0,{"cate":[{"term_id":37,"name":"Kitchen","slug":"kitchen","term_group":0,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIの方はストリーミングでレスポンスを返しているような状況ですね。

なので、受け取り側もストリーミングでレスポンスを受け取りパースする必要があります。

英語版に同じような意図の質問がありました。

[PHP HTTP Guzzle client - How to parse a JSON Array using Guzzle Streams - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65666113/php-http-guzzle-client-how-to-parse-a-json-array-using-guzzle-streams)

ここに紹介されているJsonCollectionParserを使い、ストリーミングソースとして、`$response->getBody()` を与え、パーサー関数で適切に処理すればどうでしょうか。

```php
$parser->parse($response->getBody(), function (array $item) {
    var_dump($item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

「データを分割する」という考え方の方向性自体は悪くありませんが、分割するのであれば2回目以降のやり取りでは「どの部分からのデータをやり取りするのか」の情報が必要になってくるかと思います。

例として、全部で 1,000 件のデータがあるところ 50 件ずつ分割して API がデータを返すとします。

- 1回目: "オフセット0" として 1 件目 ～ 50 件目を返す
- 2回目: "オフセット1" として 51件目 ～ 100 件目を返す

また、分割の単位も機械的に行数で分割するのではなく、できれば JSON としてのデータを保ったままレコードごとに分割する方が望ましいように思います。

この辺りは "api pagination" 等で web 検索してもらうと参考になる情報が出てくると思います。